# The text of my description is not responsive but typed text is doing well

Tags: html, css, laravel, responsive-design

I dont really know whats the reason behind it but when i use some typed text by keyboard, it is fully responsive as it should be, but when i use `$post->description` it ignores the columns and rows and its going away from the desktop.

**Here you can see how the normal text is responsive:**

[image]

```
<div class="row" style="max-width: 100vw">
     <div class="col-md-12">
         Here at L2 Arena, we have the flawless Arena Sets/Shields/Masks and Icarus Weapons.
         We believe that customized and balanced equipment make the game more exciting.

         We also have a vote system so we can rank higher and bring more people to have more fun.
         If the players are voting for L2 Arena, they will be rewarded with vote items.

         And we plan to keep our server simple, balanced and without wipes for as long as we can.
      </div>
</div>
```

**While when i want to show the post description its like this:**

[image]

```
<div class="row" style="max-width: 100vw">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        {{$post->description}}
    </div>
</div>
```

It doesnt shrink as it should be and im wondering why and how to fix this.

**EDIT: Thanks to a comment, this fixed it:**

```
<div class="row" style="max-width: 100vw">
     <div class="col-md-12" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
         {{$post->description}}
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your text looks like it's one long string, it would need a space or a soft hyphen (`&shy;`) somewhere to wrap

Comment: if you have long string without space try to use `word-wrap: break-word; `

Comment: oh dude give it as the answer so i can accept it, thanks a lot word-wrap: break-word is the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string does not have space .

use `word-wrap: break-word;`

to break lines in case that space does not exist in long string

Answer (score 0):

Check that appears with dd() el cual es equivalente a var_dump() de php en Laravel.

```
dd($post->description);
```

And tell me what appears to you.

Comment: Thank for your time, word-wrap: break-word; fixed my problem